# SQL Pivot and Coalesce

Tags: sql, r, pivot, coalesce

I have a SQL server table of phone numbers in a long format that I would like to pivot wider and condense/coalesce and save as a view. There are currently 5 different phone number types and I want to condense that down to 2 per account based on a defined priority(dropping any extra). Is this something I can do completely in a SQL query? I am currently querying and doing the manipulations in R. The reproducible example data frames are created in R.

```
original <- data.frame (Account  = c(rep("1", 3), rep("2",2), rep("3", 2)),
                  Phone.Type = c("Home", "Primary1", "Primary2", "Cell", "Primary1", "Home", "Work"),
                  Phone.Number = c("111-222-333", "222-333-4444", "333-444-5555", "444-555-6666", "555-666-7777", "666-777-8888", "777-888-9999")
                  )

priority <- c("Primary1", "Primary2", "Cell", "Home", "Work")

desiredFormat <- data.frame(Account = c("1", "2", "3"),
                           Phone.Number.1 = c("222-333-4444", "555-666-7777", "666-777-8888"),
                           Phone.Number.2 = c("333-444-5555", "444-555-6666", "777-888-9999"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLite but avoiding constructs which are specific to it,  we create a priority field and then a rank field, r, giving tmp2 and from that extract the rank 1 rows into p1 and rank 2 rows into p2. Then left join p1 to p2 on Account placing the rank 1 and rank 2 phone numbers in separate columns.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("with tmp as (select *, 
    1 * ([Phone.Type] = 'Primary1') +
    2 * ([Phone.Type] = 'Primary2') +
    3 * ([Phone.Type] = 'Cell') +
    4 * ([Phone.Type] = 'Home') +
    5 * ([Phone.Type] = 'Work') as priority
  from original),
  tmp2 as (select
      *, 
      rank() over (partition by Account order by priority) as r 
    from tmp),
  p1 as (select * from tmp2 where r = 1),
  p2 as (select * from tmp2 where r = 2)
  select p1.Account, p1.[Phone.Number] No1, p2.[Phone.Number] No2
    from p1
    left join p2 on p1.Account = p2.Account")
```

giving:

```
  Account          No1          No2
1       1 222-333-4444 333-444-5555
2       2 555-666-7777 444-555-6666
3       3 666-777-8888 777-888-9999
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

(Update: Switched to SQL Server Schema)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72d9e2/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  account int NOT NULL,
  type varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  number varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO example (account, type, number) VALUES
  (1, 'Home', '111-222-333'),
  (1, 'Primary1', '222-333-4444'),
  (1, 'Primary2', '333-444-5555'),
  (2, 'Cell', '444-555-6666'),
  (2, 'Primary1', '555-666-7777'),
  (3, 'Home', '666-777-8888'),
  (3, 'Work', '777-888-9999');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  Phone1,
  CASE WHEN Phone1 = Phone2 THEN Other ELSE Phone2 END AS Phone2
  FROM (
SELECT 
  COALESCE(Primary1, Primary2, Home, Cell, Work) AS Phone1,
  COALESCE(Primary2, Home, Cell, Work) AS Phone2,
  COALESCE(Cell, Work) AS Other
  FROM (
  SELECT account, type, number
  FROM example
 ) AS t1
 PIVOT 
 (
   MAX(number)
   FOR type IN ([Primary1], [Primary2], [Cell], [Home], [Work])
   ) AS t2
) t3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72d9e2/1/0)**:

```
|       Phone1 |       Phone2 |
|--------------|--------------|
| 222-333-4444 | 333-444-5555 |
| 555-666-7777 | 444-555-6666 |
| 666-777-8888 | 777-888-9999 |
```

Comment: Sorry for my naivety. I have an MS SQL Server schema.

Comment: @MelissaSalazar I updated my response with SQL Server schema and syntax. You may have to tinker with the COALESCE column priority order, but the basic pivot and results are there.